# Display sum of rows with same attribute, in new row below each group

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table of restaurants:

| name | year | profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| restaurant1 | 2016 | 112000 |
| restaurant1 | 2018 | 150000 |
| restaurant1 | 2020 | 165000 |
| restaurant2 | 2018 | 40000 |
| restaurant2 | 2019 | 52000 |
| restaurant3 | 2017 | 64000 |
| restaurant3 | 2018 | 73000 |
| restaurant3 | 2019 | 76000 |

I want to sum the profit of each restaurant grouped by the restaurant name, and display the total profit after each restaurant, like so:

| name | year | profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| restaurant1 | 2016 | 112000 |
| restaurant1 | 2018 | 150000 |
| restaurant1 | 2020 | 165000 |
| restaurant1 | total | 427000 |
| restaurant2 | 2018 | 40000 |
| restaurant2 | 2019 | 52000 |
| restaurant 2 | total | 92000 |
| restaurant3 | 2017 | 64000 |
| restaurant3 | 2018 | 73000 |
| restaurant3 | 2019 | 76000 |
| restaurant3 | total | 231000 |

I know that I can get the total profit of each restaurant with `SELECT SUM(profit) FROM restaurants GROUP BY restaurants.name;`

My question is how to display this result the way I have shown on the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `UNION` :

```
SELECT name, year :: text, profit FROM restaurants
UNION
(SELECT name, 'total', SUM(profit) FROM restaurants GROUP BY restaurants.name)
ORDER BY name, year
```

see the result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0b6c4b6f3bcca47407abd0733ea8ccee)